# Are there any reported changes for light and proximity sensor on Android in February 2021?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm collecting both light and proximity sensor data on Android devices and while checking the data I noticed a huge change in the amount of devices reporting both values: The percentages for devices reporting values compared to the ones not reporting info inverted:

- Until 18.02.2021: 70% no light / proximity sensor info
- After 22.02.2021: 65% with light / proximity sensor info

([Visualisation of the sensor info change between 18th and 22nd of February](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6vYr.png))

While this is nice to have there is currently no explanation for this behaviour. There was neither a change in the code at that time nor a change in our user base like a shift between Android versions. My best guess right now is a change coming from a new Android Patch

Up to now I checked the following without success:

1. Verified that no update took place at that time changing the implementation
2. Checked the Android version on the devices -> no major change explaining the issue
3. Checked the devices uses -> No major change

Is there any other source I can check to explain this behaviour or is there any other explanation?